# Can you call/use a function returned from a list in Python?

Tags: python, function, tuples

I'm trying to store a function in a list, retrieve the function from the list later, and then call on that function. This is basically what I want to do, without any specifics. It doesn't show my purpose, but it's the same issue.

```
elements: list = [] # List meant to contain a tuple with the name of the item and the function of the item.
def quit_code():
    exit()
element.append(("quit", quit_code))
```

Now, somewhere else in the code, I want to be able to use an if statement to check the name of the item and, if it's the right one at that time, run the function.

```
user_input = "quit" # For brevity, I'm just writing this. Let's just imagine the user actually typed this.
if elements[0][0] == user_input:
    #This is the part I don't understand so I'm just going to make up some syntax.
    run_method(elements[0][1])
```

The method run_method that I arbitrarily made is the issue. I need a way to run the method returned by elements[0][1], which is the quit_code method. I don't need an alternative solution to **this** example because I just made it up to display what I want to do. If I have a function or object that contains a function, how can I run that function.

(In the most simplified way I can word it) If I have object_a (for me it's a tuple) that contains str_1 and fun_b, how can I run fun_b **from the object.**

To expand on this a little more, the reason I can't just directly call the function is because in my program, the function gets put into the tuple via user input and is created locally and then stored in the tuple.

```
__list_of_stuff: list = []    
def add_to_list(name, function):
    __list_of_stuff.append((name, function))
```

And then somewhere else

```
def example_init_method():
    def stop_code():
        exit()

    add_to_list("QUIT", stop_code())
```

Now notice that I can't access the stop_code method anywhere else in the code unless I use it **through** the __list_of_stuff object.

Finally, It would be nice to not have to make a function for the input. By this, I mean directly inserting code into the parameter without creating a local function like stop_code. I don't know how to do this though.

Comment: You call a function by putting parentheses after it: `elements[0][1]()`

Comment: Barmar is right. Additionally, I recommend to use dictionary for your case. It is very common pattern which is named **dispatcher** pattern.

Comment: @Barmar Wow... that was like an hour's worth of work put into that question and Googling answers... Well thank you, I just tested it and it works. If you want to make an answer I will checkmark it or if you don't care I will create one. I don't know if you get like, extra points for your answer being marked or something but if you want to do that than whatever.

Comment: @boseong-choi Sorry I don't know what dictionary is, can you recommend a source for learning about it? I'm clearly not a proficient Googler.

Comment: To answer your second question, you can use `lambda` function. `elements.append(('quit', lambda : exit()))`

Comment: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-dictionary/

Comment: It will be helpful for your case. https://alysivji.github.io/quick-hit-dictionary-dispatch.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Python treats functions as first-class citizens. As such, you can do things like:

```
def some_function():
    # do something
    pass

x = some_function

x()
```

Since you are storing functions and binding each function with a word (key), the best approach would be a dictionary. Your example could be like this:

```
def quit_code():
    exit()

operations = dict(quit=quit_code)

operations['quit']()
```

A dictionary relates a value with a key. The only rule is the key must be immutable. That means numbers, strings, tuples and other immutable objects.

To create a dictionary, you can use { and }. And to get a value by its key, use [ and ]:

```
 my_dictionary = { 'a' : 1, 'b' : 10 }

 print(my_dictionary['a'])    # It will print 1
```

You can also create a dictionary with *dict*, like so:

```
 my_dictionary = dict(a=1, b=10)
```

However this only works for string keys.

But considering you are using quit_code to encapsulate the exit call, why not using exit directly?

```
 operations = dict(quit=exit)

 operations['quit']()
```

If dictionaries aren't an option, you could still use lists and tuples:

```
 operations = [('quit',exit)]

 for key, fun in operations:
     if key == 'quit':
         fun()
```

Comment: Thank you, I do plan on migrating to dictionaries with information from this answer and the links in peoples comments from my post. Just FYI, the reason I am not directly putting the function, like exit, into the tuple is that I will have the user input a bunch of commands at once. They might want 'create_new_file' to make a new file in some directory with some default text in it. Code like this is not just one line long and so making a function and then referencing it would be a lot easier. Just to clarify, the syntax would be (referencing my example) list_of_stuff = {"QUIT": stop_code}?